# pre filled form and edit it

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

For example, a user previously filled up a form. However, now the user wanted to edit the form.
So when he clicked on the edit button, it will bring him to a new form where the form is already prefilled with fields that he entered before.

Can I know where's the best way to do that as google doesn't have much information about it. Thank you.

Comment: Show your code to attract more help.

Comment: Can you provide more description? Why are you editing on another form? It's better to understand if you provide more code.

Comment: it's something like an event form. After it is submitted, the user might want to edit it

Comment: What have you tried so far? As said above show your code to attract more help. Have you saved the form data to firestore first? Have you fetched it and tried to populate the new form? Have you searched different approaches and something failed to work? If not try and ask again, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can use package https://pub.dev/packages/state_persistence 
In working demo you can see when app is restart `TextField` has history value 
code snippet

```
PersistedAppState(
      storage: JsonFileStorage(),
      child: MaterialApp(
     ...
            child: PersistedStateBuilder(
              builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<PersistedData> snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  if (_textController == null) {
                    _textController = TextEditingController(text: snapshot.data['text'] ?? '');
                  }
                  return TextField(
                    controller: _textController,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      hintText: 'Enter some text',
                    ),
                    onChanged: (String value) => snapshot.data['text'] = value,
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:state_persistence/state_persistence.dart';

void main() => runApp(App());

class App extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AppState createState() => _AppState();
}

class _AppState extends State<App> {
  TextEditingController _textController;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return PersistedAppState(
      storage: JsonFileStorage(),
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'Persistent TextField Example',
        theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.indigo),
        home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Persistent TextField Example')),
          body: Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(32.0),
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: PersistedStateBuilder(
              builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<PersistedData> snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  if (_textController == null) {
                    _textController = TextEditingController(text: snapshot.data['text'] ?? '');
                  }
                  return TextField(
                    controller: _textController,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      hintText: 'Enter some text',
                    ),
                    onChanged: (String value) => snapshot.data['text'] = value,
                  );
                } else {
                  return CircularProgressIndicator();
                }
              },
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: is this applicable to firebase storage?

Comment: it save to local storage.